# Memory Error:- How to get data from one dataframe to another using one common ID column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes df1 and df2. There is one ID column in common among them. I need to pull data from column df2 based on IDs in df1 however I face MemoryError as the dataframes are huge with over 3million datapoints each.

I have tried using:-

```
aq = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df2[df2['pid1'].isin(df1['shortId'])]))
```

but it runs into Memory Error. Is there any efficient way to do this?

The dataframe looks like this:-

df1:-

```
ShortID x   y   z
qwe 1   1   1
asd 1   1   1
zxc 1   1   1
rty 1   1   1
fgh 1   1   1
vbn 1   1   1
```

df2:-

```
pid1    pid2    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
qwe qasd    values  values  values  values
asd uio values  values  values  values
zxc plm values  values  values  values
rty okn values  values  values  values
fgh uhb values  values  values  values
vbn tgv values  values  values  values
qasd    qwe values  values  values  values
uio asd values  values  values  values
plm zxc values  values  values  values
okn rty values  values  values  values
uhb fgh values  values  values  values
tgv vbn values  values  values  values
```

The result should appear like this:-

```
ShortID x   y   z   Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
qwe 1   1   1   values  values  values  values
asd 1   1   1   values  values  values  values
zxc 1   1   1   values  values  values  values
rty 1   1   1   values  values  values  values
fgh 1   1   1   values  values  values  values
vbn 1   1   1   values  values  values  values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) should be more efficient:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='ShortID', right_on='pid1', how='left').drop(columns=['pid1','pid2'])
```

If this still throws a memory error, you may want to use [dask dataframes](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html?highlight=merge#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.merge), i.e. read the data into dask dataframes and merge them the same way as written above (except that dask 2.2.0 doesn't support the `columns` parameter in [`drop`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.drop), so you must use `.drop('rkey', axis=1)`)